# interface providerspec prevented connection from:content_utility to: content_browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, vps

I have python 2.7 selenium script using chromedriver that works on my home windows 7 machine, but when I run it on windows VPS, I'm getting this error: *interface providerspec prevented connection from:content_utility to: content_browser*
Google does not give any help. Im restarting the program when there is any error and this is the function I use for it which I think causes the problem.

```
    def restart_program():
"""Restarts the current program, with file objects and descriptors
   cleanup
"""

try:
    p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    for handler in p.get_open_files() + p.connections():
        os.close(handler.fd)
except Exception, e:
    logging.error(e)

python = sys.executable
os.execl(python, python, *sys.argv)

def vypinac():
    print("vypinac jede")
    subprocess.Popen.terminate(pchat)
    driver.quit()
    restart_program()
```

Comment: What version of windows is Windows VPS running? This might sound obvious but do you have all of the dependencies installed on that machine? I am specifically referring to chromedriver as this error appears to indicate that the browser is not launching.

Comment: Yes there are all dependencies installed.. the browser is running and the VPS server uses Windows Server 2012 R2. Maybe there is some security settings which could cause this? I really have no idea.

Comment: That seems possible but based on that error I am also unsure. I will upvote the question to see if there's any traction. Otherwise check to see what ports are open/listening. When I run chromedriver I get the following: Starting ChromeDriver 2.25.426935 (820a95b0b81d33e42712f9198c215f703412e1a1) on port 9515